# Bazel Build Mnist Serving Interface Fail on OSX El Capitan

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to build the TensorFlow serving basic tutorial on OSX El Capitan but run into this error. Any ideas?

Here's the link to the tutorial: https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic

```
$ bazel build //tensorflow_serving/example:mnist_inference
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /Users/robertgrzesik/Documents/Development/TensorFlow/serving/tensorflow_serving/example/BUILD:53:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow_serving/example:mnist_inference' failed: osx_gcc_wrapper.sh failed: error executing command external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/osx_gcc_wrapper.sh -o bazel-out/local_darwin-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_inference ... (remaining 512 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: warning: option -noall_load is obsolete and being ignored
ld: warning: option -noall_load is obsolete and being ignored
ld: warning: option -noall_load is obsolete and being ignored
ld: warning: option -noall_load is obsolete and being ignored
ld: warning: option -noall_load is obsolete and being ignored
ld: warning: option -noall_load is obsolete and being ignored
```

This change was also made to my WORKSPACE file (based on [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/6) discussion):

```
git_repository(
    name = "boringssl_git",
    commit = "32bfe16a53ad13523eadce08dd2f835bc2b0b52d",
    init_submodules = True,
    remote = "https://github.com/ctiller/boringssl-bazel",
)
```

Comment: Found a temporary fix to use docker. Seems like there are known issues with OSX right now: http://tensorflow.github.io/serving/docker

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary fix to use docker. Seems like there are known issues with OSX right now.

Docker install instructions can be found here: http://tensorflow.github.io/serving/docker